# Prove or disprove: If H is a normal subgroup of G such that H and G/H are abelian, then G is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

it seems like it... should be? In that I can't think of any counterexamples off the top of my head. I was looking up these http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_group and saw the quaternion group, but the subgroups of the quaternion group aren't abelian...

Comment: "but the subgroups of the quaternion group aren't abelian" not all of them, no, but then again the original claim doesn't say anything about "all of the subgroups" ... have you even tried to find a normal subgroup H of the quaternion group and tested if H and G/H are abelian?

Comment: {1, -1, i, -i} is an abelian subgroup of Q8, but G/H isn't abelian. Guess I'll go with Nicky Hekster's example.

Comment: All proper subgroups and proper quotients of $Q_8$ are abelian (and all subgroups are normal).

Comment: I guess I don't get what the quotient group really is, then. I was considering {1, -1, i, -i} as the normal subgroup, so an abelian quotient group would be j*k{1, -1, i, -1} = k*j{1, -1, i, -i}? But j*k =/= k*j so, what am I failing to grasp here.

Comment: You do need to know what normal groups and quotient groups are in order to do this problem. The subgroup {1,-1,i,-i} is *not* normal in the quaternion group. Also it is possible for a,b to be distinct elements in a group (like jk versus kj) but for aH=bH in the quotient group, so your "But ..." at the end of your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @anon yes it is normal. As I mentioned above, all subgroups of $Q_8$ are normal.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Not true: try $G=S_3$, with $H=A_3$. By the way the following is true. A group is called *metabelian* if $G''=1$ (the commutator subgroup of the commutator subgroup is trivial). If $H \unlhd G$ is abelian with $G/H$ abelian, then $G' \subseteq H$ and hence $G'' \subseteq H' = {1}$. The other way around, if $G$ is metabelian then $G'$ is an abelian normal subgroup and $G/G'$ is of course abelian. So the property in the post occurs only in the class of metabelian groups. $S_3$ is an example of a non-abelian metabelian group. There are many more, like $Q$, the quaternion group of order $8$ as discussed above, or $S_3 \times Q$.